# Working with interfaces using Viper language

Tags: go, viper-go

I am building a little app using [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) and [Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra). At the moment, I have a yaml file like this:

```
hosts:
  - name: host1
    port: 90
    key: my_key
  - name: host2
    port: 90
    key: prompt
```

And I've read in the config file using Viper.

When I run `viper.Get("hosts")` it returns an interface (or a slice of interfaces?). This is the data structure I end up with:

```
([]interface {}) (len=2 cap=2) {
 (map[interface {}]interface {}) (len=3) {
  (string) (len=4) "name": (string) (len=20) "host1",
  (string) (len=4) "port": (int) 90,
  (string) (len=3) "key": (string) (len=6) "my_key"
 },
 (map[interface {}]interface {}) (len=3) {
  (string) (len=3) "key": (string) (len=6) "prompt",
  (string) (len=4) "name": (string) (len=20) "host2",
  (string) (len=4) "port": (int) 90
 }
}
```

What I'd like to do here is loop over each of the array elements and perform an operation using the values of name, port and key.

I'm completely new to interfaces in Golang, so this isn't very clear, and the literature on this is extremely confusing :(

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By defining the configuration file type and using `viper.Unmarshal` you can cast the interface to the specific type you need. Here is an example:

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Host struct {
    Name string
    Port int
    Key  string
}

type Config struct {
    Hosts []Host
}

func main() {
    viper.AddConfigPath("./")
    viper.SetConfigName("test")
    viper.ReadInConfig()
    var config Config
    err := viper.Unmarshal(&config)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Unable to unmarshal config")
    }
    for _, h := range config.Hosts {
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s, Port: %d, Key: %s\n", h.Name, h.Port, h.Key)
    }
}
```

`test.yml`

```
hosts:
  - name: host1
    port: 90
    key: my_key
  - name: host2
    port: 90
    key: prompt
```

Run:

```
$ go run main.go
Name: host1, Port: 90, Key: my_key
Name: host2, Port: 90, Key: prompt
```

If you want to decode only some keys, not the entire configuration file, use `viper.UnmarshalKey`.

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Host struct {
    Name string
    Port int
    Key  string
}

func main() {
    viper.AddConfigPath("./")
    viper.SetConfigName("test")
    viper.ReadInConfig()
    var hosts []Host
    err := viper.UnmarshalKey("hosts", &hosts)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Unable to unmarshal hosts")
    }
    for _, h := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s, Port: %d, Key: %s\n", h.Name, h.Port, h.Key)
    }
}
```

Run:

```
$ go run main.go
Name: host1, Port: 90, Key: my_key
Name: host2, Port: 90, Key: prompt
```